# Return only numeric value and display in a single column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
SQL> select * from id_proof(source_table);

PANNO                ADHARNO              COLLEGEID
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
BMBDD7715A           80DJ21761128         09751A123
PJ3AB1234B           567817231111         09751217
QDXAZ1723B           1127525423           111777A123
ZPBJT15623           27524397111          234725484
```

Above one is my source table and I want to below output.

```
Target
------
80DJ21761128
567817231111
1127525423
27524397111
09751217
234725484
```

**Note**-:First four row values are from adharno column and last two row values are from collegeid(Numeric only).

Comment: Is it on purpose to select '80DJ21761128' which contains non-digits ('D' and 'J')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
select adharno as target
  from id_proof(source_table)
union all
select collegeid
  from id_proof(source_table)
 where regexp_like( collegeid, '^[[:digit:]]*$' )
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. I don't what is wrong in above query may be instr. below query is working fine for me                                                                                                                                                                    "select adharno target
  from id_proof
union all
select collegeid
  from id_proof
 where regexp_like( collegeid, '^[[:digit:]]*$')"

Comment: @GyanendraKumar . . . Either Justin intended `> 0` or `regexp_like()`.  Either way, the intention clearly works, so you can accept this answer.